# Another illogical tag merger

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

The illogical Vishnu-Narayana merger might be tied to religious beliefs some sects have.

Today I discovered that "Varanasi" is not allowed as a tag - it maps to "kashi".

Why are simple matters turned into contentious issues at HSE?

Comment: what is illogical here?

Comment: I knew that Varanasi, Benaras, Kashi denote the same city until I saw your post.

Comment: @Rickross it's same only.. Kashi Khanda of Skanda Purana says many names for city kāsi like Varanasi, Avimukta, Rudravana, Mahasmashana.. now, if someone comes and date Kashi khanda and gives a date, we can't do anything..Shastra Pramana and words of Acharyas are ultimate here not scholars who date scriptures or places.

Comment: I now remember why the thought of being a mod didn't even cross my mind. Requires lot of patience

Answer (score -1):

Monier Williams dictionary:

> vārāṇasī f. the city Benares (more properly written Banāras; accord. to JābālUp.  so called after the names of two rivers, varaṇā and asi, or asī; also written vāṇārasī, q.v., varāṇasī or vāraṇasī), MBh. ; Kāv.  &c. [ID=191726]

> 1 vārāṇasī
> 2 vārāṇasīdarpaṇa
> 3 vārāṇasīmāhātmya
> 4 vārāṇasīśvara
> 5 vārāṇaseya

> kāśi a is, m. ‘shining’, the sun, L.  [ID=49833]
> the clenched hand, fist, handful, RV. iii, 30, 5; vii, 104, 8; viii, 78, 10; Kauś.  [ID=49834]
> N. of a prince (the ancestor of the kings of Kāśi, of the family of Bharata, son of Suhotra and grandfather of Dhanvantari, Hariv. 1734; the son of Kāśya and grandson of Suhotra, BhP. ix, 17, 4 ) [ID=49835]
> (ayas), m. pl. (ayas) the descendants of this prince, BhP. ix, 17, 10  [ID=49836]
> N. of the people of Kāśi, ŚBr. xiii ; MBh.  &c. [ID=49837]
> kāśi (is), f. ‘the splendid’, N. of a celebrated city and place of pilgrimage (the modern Benares, usually written Kāśī q.v.), Uṇ. iv, 119  [ID=49838]
> fine cotton or silk (from Kāśi), Divyāv.  [ID=49839]

> 1 kāśi
> 2 kāśikanyā
> 3 kāśikosalīya
> 4 kāśikhaṇḍa
> 5 kāśinagara
> 6 kāśinātha
> 7 kāśipa
> 8 kāśipati
> 9 kāśipurī
> 10 kāśimanuja
> 11 kāśirāja
> 12 kāśirājan
> 13 kāśirāma
> 14 kāśivardhana
> 15 kāśivilāsa
> 16 kāśika
> 17 kāśikā
> 18 kāśikavastra
> 19 kāśikasūkṣma
> 20 kāśikātilaka
> 21 kāśikānyāsa
> 22 kāśikāpriya
> 23 kāśikāvivaraṇapañjikā
> 24 kāśin
> 25 kāśila
> 26 kāśiṣṇu

They are synonyms, and also not synonyms.

Legitimate questions like "which name is more ancient - kasi or Varanasi?" cannot be properly tagged the way things are.

Kashi was also the name of a kingdom.  Bard AI says

> The Kingdom of Kashi was an ancient Indian kingdom located in the present-day Indian state of Uttar Pradesh. It was one of the sixteen Mahajanapadas, or great kingdoms, of ancient India. The kingdom was centered around the city of Varanasi, which is considered to be one of the holiest cities in Hinduism.

This is just for the record - I know that nothing will be done about it.